Android app no ​longer works correctly after distribution via Google Play
I programmed a simple Android app.
It consists of little more than a WebView and is simply a wrapper app for a web application.
When I log in to the web application, my login details are stored in a cookie.
When I quit and restart the app, this cookie remains in memory. So I don't have to log in every time I close the app.
When I install this app from the .apk file, everything works fine without errors as described above.
If I upload this app to Google Play as a bundle (.aab) file and install it from there, the app changes its behavior.
Now the cookie is lost after exiting the app. Now I have to log in again every time I restart the app.
Does anyone have any idea what could be the reason for this?
I tried to store all cookies in a separate file and to restore all cookies from there after starting the app. But that did not help.

When I quit and restart the app, this cookie remains in memory. Are  you using CookieManager?
